# What is correct way to use Flask-SQLAlchemy in Flask server?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is model code, I have tested this code, it is no error and it can create tables, records in DB

createdb.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/ai'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == 'createdb':
    db.reflect()
    db.drop_all()
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Class(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    label = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Class %r>' % self.username

class Photo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    path = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Photo %r>' % self.username

class PhotoClass(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    photoId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('photo.id'), nullable=False)
    classId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.id'), nullable=False)
    score = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, photoId, classId):
        self.photoId = photoId
        self.classId = classId

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PhotoClass %r>' % self.username

if __name__ == 'createdb':
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(Class('Plain'))
    db.session.add(Class('Printed'))
    db.session.commit()
```

This is server code

app.py

```
import createdb

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    createdb.db.session.add(createdb.Class('aaa'))
    createdb.db.session.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If I import to server, it is still no error, when I go to localhost:5000, I will get this error

```
track_modifications = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']
KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'
```

---

This is full error

```
[2018-10-30 18:31:03,288] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 999, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: 12344

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "E:\0\airbtn\yeetungaiserver\app.py", line 17, in index
    createdb.db.session.add(createdb.Class('aaa'))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 153, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 1001, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2950, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    track_modifications = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']
KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'
```

Comment: Please put full error stacktrace. Which line is causing this? Which file stacktrace mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

In `createdb.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/ai'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == 'createdb':
    db.reflect()
    db.drop_all()
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

you create an instance of `Flask` called `app` and pass that to the `SQLAlchemy` constructor assigning the result to the variable, `db` (you actually do this twice when you import `createdb` from `app.py`). They key point is that `db` is instantiated referencing the `Flask` instance `createdb.app`.

Then in app.py:

```
import createdb  # createdb.app is created upon import

app = Flask(__name__)  # but you create a new `Flask` instance called app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # all of the below db operations occur on createdb.db which is in the 
    # createdb.app context, not the context of app created in this module
    createdb.db.session.add(createdb.Class('aaa'))
    createdb.db.session.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # the app you run here, isn't the app that was made available to db in 
    # in createdb.py. It has no idea what db is!
    app.run()
    # try createdb.app.run()
```

I've annotated your app.py code above with more detail but the short of it is that the `app.run()` call in `app.py` isn't called on the `app` that `createdb.db` is aware of.