# KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I tried to get query from database but failed by KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'.
My code is

```
@app.route("/users/<int:id>")
def users(id):
result = Account.query.get(id)    
return render_template("users.html",username=result.username).
```

I think syntax on query is mistake. Need suggestions !!!

Comment: Have you gone through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274152/flask-sqlalchemy-keyerror-sqlalchemy-track-modifications and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062408/what-is-correct-way-to-use-flask-sqlalchemy-in-flask-server?

Answer (score 0):

Major problem is not instantiating of session object
Now code is

```
@app.route("/users/<int:id>")
def users(id):
    session = Session()
    result = session.query(Account).filter_by(id=id).first()
    return render_template("users.html", result = result)`
```

in users.html is

```
<ul>
    <li>id: {{ result.id }} </li>
    <li>username: {{ result.username }} </li>
    <li>password: {{ result.password }} </li>
</ul>`
```